# execle() environment variable not working

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am starting to learn about operating systems, I tried using the execle() system call in C, I have a DIR environment variable which I set to /home using the environment array like this

```
char* path = "/bin/ls";
char* myargs[4] = {"ls", "-la", "/home", NULL};
char *const env[] = {"DIR=/home", NULL};
execle(path, myargs[0], myargs[1], "$DIR", NULL, env);
```

But when I compile and run this I get the following output
`ls: cannot access '$DIR': No such file or directory`

However, this seems to work just fine
`execle("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $DIR", NULL, env);`

Is there something I am understanding wrong about execle call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec*e` family of functions doesn't expand environment variables themselves, they just pass the environment on to the new program for its `getenv` calls.

The call

```
execle("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $DIR", NULL, env);
```

works because it's the shell you invoke that does the expanding of the `$DIR` environment variable, it's not expanded by your program or the `execle` function.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the quick response. So that's the reason something like execle("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -la $DIR", NULL, env) would work.